# DataGridView.Font isn't updating visually

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview

I'm developing a dialogue to configure a DataGridView's appearance. Everything works quite well until the DataGridView should be redrawn because it's font has changed. All DataGridViews have a base class that overrides Font's getter to grab the chosen Font.

I'm trying to update my DGVs like that:

```
public static void RefreshAllConfigurationForms(Control parent)
{
    var controls = parent.GetChildControls(typeof(ConfigurableDataGridView));

    if (controls != null)
    {
        foreach (var configurableControl in controls)
        {
            configurableControl.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging
    configurableControl.Refresh();
the DGV's Font is set properly but it's not updating visually. Actually I noticed that InheritedEditingCellStyle's Font is still the old one.

The Font is set in a derivation of DataGridView:

```
public class ConfigurableDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    public override System.Drawing.Font Font
    {
        get
        {
            return AppearanceConfiguration.Font;
        }
    }
}
```

So is there any way to force a redraw "even more"?

**Further information:**
The DataGridView is part of a TabControl. When opening a new tab the font is properly rendered but when changing the font the DGV just doesn't update.

Comment: This is never necessary, changing a Font property is already enough to trigger a repaint.  So if that doesn't work then Refresh() is not 'ever more' going to work.  Ask the real question instead.

Comment: So I guess the real question is: "Why isn't my DGV not updating when I'm setting its font?" Or in other words: "What could possibly prevent my DGV from updating?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the parent form of my DataGridView prevented it to update its visuals. So when calling Refresh on that (embedded) form the DataGridView updates as expected.

Comment: I presume this was the final solution? If so, well done for finding it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `MyForm.Paint()`? I believe this should redraw all child items as well as the form itself.

Comment: Unfortunately this had no effect